# What aircraft manufacturer uses an HSI with DME, VOR, and G/S in one Instrument?

Tags: navigation, avionics, flight-instruments

Which aircraft manufacturer uses a horizontal situation indicator (HSI) with DME, Glide Slope, VOR, and ADF in one Instrument?

Comment: The Garmin G1000 can do that... but I'm thinking you are wanting the old "steam" type instrument?

Comment: The Rockwell Collins 331A-9G is mechanical and includes all the above except for the ADF. Which is doubtful to find except in digital HSI's.

Comment: Likewise, the Collins Proline 21 (and I assume most other Glass cockpits) can do the same with multiple pointers on the PFD or MFD.